# Checking indexed object value type

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary: `dict = {"key":[None, "item 2", "item 3"]}`

How can I check that `dict["key"][0] is None` **if "key" is unknown**.

I have this so far:

```
{k: dict[k][0] for k in dict.viewkeys()}
```

which gives me:

```
{"key":None}
```

In my application, I am testing to see if `dict["key"][0]` has been populated yet, its default is None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. If you want all key, value pairs such that the first item in the value list is `None`, you could do this:

```
unassigned_items = {k:v for k, v in mydict.viewitems() if v[0] is None}
```

Note that you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name because it masks the `dict` built-in -- even in example code, if only because it may mislead people.

Once you've got `unassigned_items`, you can simply test to see if `'key'` is in `unassigned_items`:

```
if key in unassigned_items:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the safest/cleanest:

```
if d[d.keys()[0]][0] is None: print "Empty"
```

Comment: If this were what the OP wanted -- and I'm not sure that it is -- then why wouldn't the OP simply use `"key4" in d`?  Definitely shouldn't use a bare except, in any event.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. I thought that they were asking if the key might not exist yet, not if you didn't know the key name.

Comment: if d[d.keys()[0]][0] is None: print "Empty"

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try filter(lambda k: dict[k][0] == None, dict.keys())

should return a list of all the members of dict.keys() (the list of keys) whose first element is None (that is, they return True for dict[k][0] == None)